# Troubleshouting laravel migrations for new database

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to set a separate database for tests. For some reason when I run the migrations I have always a message saying: "Nothing to migrate."

Here is how I run the migrations:

```
php artisan migrate --database=mysql_test
Nothing to migrate.
```

And here is my config/database.php:

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'connections' => [

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
],

'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'dev'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],

'mysql_test' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbtest'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'dev'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

And obviously I can login to the database mydbtest with the credentials in the config.

Updating here after some troubleshooting:
After emptying mydb database and running the same command it filled the mydb database not mydbtest. This means it does not take into account what I am giving as database connection name.

Any suggestions to troubleshoot this are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

After commenting out this line in my .env file it works now:

```
#DB_DATABASE=mydb
```

Thanks